# How to launch Excel application when setup is complete?

Tags: c#, excel, wix

I made an installer using WIX and added a checkbox to setup with purpose to start Excel if its checked. But I don't now what to put in custom action. This is a code for checkbox from [here](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=12199):

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch Microsoft Excel" />  
 <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1" /> 
 <Property Id="EXCELSRCH"> 
    <RegistrySearch Id="ExcelSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWAREMicrosoftWindowsCurrentVersionApp Pathsexcel.exe" Name="Path" Type="raw" /> 
</Property>
```

How do I make this checkbox work?
P.S.  I am completely newbie on Wix and programming at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the WiX help topic:

[How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help.